# How to add UserControl inside Window and assign x:Name

Tags: c#, wpf

First of all sorry for my english and sorry again, I'm beginner and maybe I try to do something that is not possible.

My goal is create a UserControl to reuse the code in different windows/pages/usercontrols using different parameters. I developed a class to print boxes to track objects over a video.

Well my problem is while compiling I recieve the follow error:

> Name 'mediaBoxes' does not exist in the current context

If I change:

```
<local:MediaBoxes x:Name="mediaBoxes"></local:MediaBoxes>
```

instead of

```
<local:MediaBoxes Name="mediaBoxes"></local:MediaBoxes>
```

I recieved the follow error:

> The type name MediaBoxes does not exist in the type MyModule

If I remove the attribute Name and I do not call to InitVideo, all code compile, and can execute perfect.. but my player is always loading because I need initialize the instance.

Simplifying my code, I have:

InfoPage.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyModule.InfoPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyModule"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance  local:InfoPage}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="PlayerBoxes" />
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="containerVideo">
            <local:MediaBoxes Name="mediaBoxes"></local:MediaBoxes>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

InfoPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Fulcrum.Model;
using Genetec.Sdk;
using Genetec.Sdk.Workspace;
using MyModule.Helpers;

namespace MyModule
{
    public partial class InfoPage : Window
    {
        #region Constructors
        public InfoPage(SearchPage mainTaskUc, ODetection det)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _detection = det;
            mainTask = mainTaskUc;

            DataContext = this;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public void Initialize(Workspace workspace)
        {
            if (workspace == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("workspace");

            Workspace = workspace;
            _sdkEngine = Workspace.Sdk;

            Show();

            mediaBoxes.InitVideo(mainTask.SearchSelectedClips[0], _detection, _sdkEngine);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

And the mediaBoxes is a user control with:

MediaBoxes.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyModule.MediaBoxes"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyModule"
         xmlns:media="clr-namespace:Genetec.Sdk.Media;assembly=Genetec.Sdk.Media"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Colors.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Fonts.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Texts.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Name="containerVideo" Grid.Row="0">
            <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="{StaticResource GreyDark4Brush}"
                    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mediaPlayer}"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=mediaPlayer}"
                    Visibility="Collapsed">
                <media:MediaPlayer Name="mediaPlayer"
                                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=containerVideo}"
                                   Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=containerVideo}" />

                <Canvas Name="CanvasBoxes" />

                <Canvas Name="CanvasControls">
                    <TextBlock Name="plyrBoxesCameraTitle" Canvas.Top="24" Canvas.Left="24" Foreground="LightGray" />
                    <TextBlock Name="plyrBoxesDateTime" Canvas.Top="56" Canvas.Left="24" Foreground="LightGray" />
                    <Button Name="plyrBoxesBookmarkBtn" Canvas.Top="24" Canvas.Right="24">
                        <Button.Content>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xE867;"
                                       Foreground="LightGray" />
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Grid Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0"
                          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=CanvasControls}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="24" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Button Name="plyrBoxesVolumeOnBtn">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xE050;"
                                                   Foreground="LightGray" />
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Name="plyrBoxesVolumeOffBtn" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xE04F;"
                                                   Foreground="LightGray" />
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Button Name="plyrBoxesPlayBtn" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xE037;"
                                                   Foreground="LightGray" />
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Name="plyrBoxesPauseBtn">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xE034;"
                                                   Foreground="LightGray" />
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Name="plyrBoxesRestartSequenceBtn">
                                    <Button.Content>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialIcons}" Text="&#xE5D5;"
                                                   Foreground="LightGray" />
                                    </Button.Content>
                                </Button>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <TextBlock Name="plyrBoxesCurrentTime" Foreground="LightGray" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Canvas>

            </Canvas>

            <StackPanel Name="loadingVideoPlayer" Visibility="Visible"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LoadingSpinningText}" FontSize="52" Width="52" Height="52" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0 16">Loading Video</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

and MediaBoxes.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Genetec.Sdk;

namespace MyModule
{
public partial class MediaBoxes : UserControl
{
    public MediaBoxes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private IEngine _sdkEngine;
    private SearchSelectedClipModel _selectedCamera;
    private ODetection _detection;

    public void InitVideo(SearchSelectedClipModel selectedCamera, ODetection detection, IEngine sdkEngine)
    {
        _sdkEngine = sdkEngine;
        _selectedCamera = selectedCamera;
        _detection = detection;

        ...
}
```

A lot of thanks!!!

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I found the real problem.. My code didn't have any problem... But I had defined a class in root path with the same name of my namespace. -.-'

Thanks all for your help!!

Comment: To be honest not sure why this does not work, but you can give a name to your DockPanel and and get your control from its Children property

Comment: Yes you are right.. it works fine.. but I don't like it because this code will be used for other programmers integrate with my "library" in his solutions.

Comment: other way would be to make a getter for your control that takes it from dockpanel children. Like `public MediaBoxes MediaBox => (MediaBoxes) DockPanel.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x is MediaBoxes);`

Answer (score 0):

Some ui things can have a Name, some can't. You don't need to name your control though.

Your usercontrol is a frameworkelement and it will therefore have the standard events.
That included initialized and loaded.
You could hook either of those with an eventhandler via XAML.

```
 <local:MediaBoxes Initialized="MediaBoxes_Initialized"/>
```

If you type in initialized= then you can accept the stub event handler it gives you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, I'm very beginner and I didn't know that I cannot control my control by name. The solution that you proposed works fine too, but it's no have way to can interact with my control using directly the name? What I need to change? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You can use x:Name on a usercontrol, no problem. Are you sure there's no other error or another control with the same name in the same namescope? If you clean your project, does the problem go away?

Comment: I checked and no, it is not another usercontrol with the same name. When you say namescope is MyModule??? No changes cleaning the project. The error is:  The type name 'MediaBoxes' does not exist in the type 'MyModule'

Comment: It looks in your exe and there is no MediaBoxes in it.  Which means it's not compiled. Take the usercontrol out the page temporarily. Does your project definitely really build?

Answer (score -1):

You need to give name as per following

```
<local:MediaBoxes x:Name="mediaBoxes"></local:MediaBoxes>
```

because your usercontrol 'MediaBoxes' and 'Window' are in same namespace (MyModule) so if you will write following

```
<local:MediaBoxes Name="mediaBoxes"></local:MediaBoxes>
```

you will get following error

```
Because 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode' is implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute rather than the Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Xaml.LanguageService.Semantics.Metadata.ReflectionPropertyNode attribute.
```

So give name to you usercontrol in following way

```
<local:MediaBoxes x:Name="mediaBoxes"></local:MediaBoxes>
```

and in code behind access it using following

```
mediaBoxes.InitVideo(mainTask.SearchSelectedClips[0], _detection, _sdkEngine);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I asume that I need to give name with x:Name ;) . I already inserted the attribute x:Name and, as in my question said, the compiler returns an error:

Name 'mediaBoxes' does not exist in the current context